# How to set color for a button in Xcode7?

Tags: xcode, swift2, xcode7

Hi Im new to Xcode7 and Swift2 and I am trying to change the color of the buttons I am adding to my storyboard.  Is there a way to change the color of the button in Xcode7?  All I see are options to change color of text and add background image to a button but no change button color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button has many parts / aspects, so what do you mean by the "button color"? You probably mean the button's *background color*. If you scroll down in the button's attributes inspector, you'll come to the background color. The reason it's so far down is that it's a View (UIView) property, not merely a button (UIButton) property.

Comment: I am soooo embarassed right now.  Coming from an android development background this xcode7 scroll interface is invisible to my eyes I honestly thought that I have scrolled deep enough.  Thank you so much next time I will scroll to the very end on every tab possible.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Done sir accepted.  Sorry stackoverflow did not allow me to accept it 6 mins after I posted the question :)

Comment: By the way there are system settings that can make scrollability more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll look into it ASAP